# Including google tests in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, project-structure

I'm trying to start testing my Qt project with Google tests. I read [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-autotest.html), but there is only description, how to create and run tests, but not integrate. So I had some questions.

1. Should I create subproject or create separate one? Where should I place test project?

Now I store test project this way:

```
project.pro
|
 --- subproject1.pri
|
 --- subproject2.pri
|
| ...
|
 --- test_project.pri
    |
     --- init_tests.cpp
```

Is that correct way to place tests?

2. From where should I run this code?

`::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
 return RUN_ALL_TESTS();`

Now I run it from `init_tests.cpp`. Then I call `init_tests` from `main` function. It seems wrong, but I don't know another way to do this.

3. So if I use previously described way to integrate tests, how can I remove it from deployment?
4. Where should I place tests in git repo? I created branch for my tests, then merge it to master. Is that correct?

Thanks for answers, sorry for my broken English.

Comment: Why bring in a separate test framework when there's already one built into Qt?

Comment: Because if I will write non-qt project, I just need to integrate google test library into it and I will familiar with it.

Comment: By the way, QtCreator supports google test integration, many people consider google tests more attractive. So why should not I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question 4 : that seems correct for the first implementation, but then this branch must die, you don't want to have a branch with the test. Commit made on any branches must included related Unit Test and must be pushed only when tests are green...

Answer to question 1/2 : Your tests should be in a standalone executable that should not be shipped to your client.. Normally you have one pro file per executable target. So I would rather do :

```
project.pro
|
 --- subproject1.pri
|
 --- subproject2.pri
|
| ...
|
test_project.pro
 --- test_project.pri
    |
     --- main.cpp
```

With main.cpp holding your lines :

```
:testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
 return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

.. suddently it becomes obvious , don't you think ?

(and of course only test_project.pro contains include and reference to Google Test )

Answer to question 3 : become obvious too.

Note : for that to work it supposes that what you do in subproject1 and subproject2 is accessible, i.e that those libs are either static and included in test_project.pro or dynamic lib with exported symbols.